# android app wont build due to "Versions that do not match"

Tags: java, android, maven, android-studio, intellij-idea

i started a new android app project and haven't done anything so far except opening a new project. The initial build fails and i get the error message below. It tells me to install the support repository but it is already fully installed. (im new to andoid development so i have no clue whats going on)

```
Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+.
Versions that do not match:
  - 26.0.0-alpha1
  - 25.3.1
  - 25.3.0
  - 25.2.0
  - 25.1.1
  - + 50 more
Searched in the following locations:
  - file:/home/corb/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  - file:/home/corb/Android/Sdk/extras/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
  - file:/home/corb/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  - file:/home/corb/Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
  - file:/home/corb/Android/Sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml
  - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/
Required by:
    project :app

Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.
Open Android SDK Manager
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.finances"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Comment: click on `Open Android SDK Manager` and install `Android Support Repository`

Comment: It is already installed as i stated in the original question

Comment: So can you attach your apps build.gradle? also try to rename `29.+` with `26.0.0-alpha1` and see what will happens.

Comment: How do i do that. Again im completly new to android and have no clue where to go or what to do to fix something

Comment: copy your build.gradle file here please.

Comment: '''
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
        
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
'''

Comment: put your apps build.gradle. the one you use to add your dependencies.

Comment: too long for a comment.. edit it into the post

Comment: in your dependencies change `29.+` with `26.0.0-alpha1` and sync. if the problem solved then it means you do not have `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:29.+'`

Comment: Now it doesn't doe anything when i try to build it.. what the heck is going on

Answer (score 0):

There are two parts to installing an Android SDK, there is the Code Part, which you will download by opening the SDK Manager, highlighting SDK Platforms, choosing the version you want to download, and clicking Apply.  Then, there is the Platform Tools part, which you will highlight SDK Tools at the top, then select the Android SDK Build-Tools for the same SDK version that you downloaded, and clicking Apply.  Have you done both of these when you say that "it is already fully installed"?

Comment: Yes.. i now installed a second version to test if something changes but no it doesn't

Comment: OK, as others are saying above, look in your project listing, you should have a folder called app, and below that one called Gradle Scripts.  Expand Gradle Scripts and you should see a file called build.gradle (Module:app).  Open that and look down to the area that is called dependencies, copy and paste that here.  If you compile your app, do you get any warnings or errors in this file?  If so, those warnings should say that versions don't match, and tell you what version number it is trying to match.